# Get server path minus file name in PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP script I am writing that will be used on more than one server.  So it could be at any of these:

```
/home/14535/domains/something.com/html/miller/test/index.php
/home/12345/domains/something.com/html/jones/test/dir4/index.php
/home/11112/domains/something.com/html/smith/test/test2/test3/index.html
```

in any above case in need to return the full path minus the index.php or index.html

How can I **reliably** return the full server path of the current directory MINUS the actual script name? (There will be some image uploading etc and that is why I need this path).

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Use [`dirname($file)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

Comment: or [pathinfo()](http://php.net/pathinfo) if you want arbitrary path components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

example from php manual

```
  <?php
  $path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

 echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
 echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
 echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
 echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
 ?>
```

Comment: Several of these worked but I like the way this breaks out the parts, should I need theme elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`__FILE__` returns the full path and script currently running. To get the directory name run it through `dirname()`. If you have a symbolic link you'll also need to pass this through `realpath()`

```
realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
```

This is probably what you are looking for. This, for example, returns the correct path on my server

```
root@upstairslinux:~# php example.php
/root

root@upstairslinux:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
$yourpath = dirname(__FILE__);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP 5.3+ you should use the magic constant:

```
__DIR__
```

If your version is below this, you should use:

```
dirname(__FILE__);
```

If you have a version below 4.0.2, upgrade your PHP version ;)

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php for more information.